# Dynamic range for y axis (Plotly - Python)

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

When I put autorange bar graph shows not as good as posible. Then I decided to put fixed range, but my graph sometimes out of y axis.
So I want to put dynamic range [0, df[‘yaxis’][-1] + 500]. It shows error: like it is out of band.

```
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(
barmode=‘group’,
bargap=0.15,
bargroupgap=0.1,
yaxis={‘range’:([0, cumulative_df[‘max’][-1] + 500])}
)
```

How to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has this option with the [max() function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) across a specific column of values in the dataframe you're using for your Y. As the dataframe changes, so does the range.